How to implement a Hilbert Transformer? (to know reasons of delay & complexity)
The phase shift method (Hilbert Transformer) can be used for single sideband (SSB) generation. It is easy to build a circuit to shift the phase of a single frequency component by /. But a device to achieve this phase shift for all the spectral components over a band of frequencies is unrealizable. We can, at best, approximate it over a finite band. The reason, as I know from a previous question, is the large delay and complexity.
I need the DSP implementation for the Hilbert Transformer to know the reasons of delay and complexity for a wide band of frequency.

You're doing too many questions per question post. That makes it additionally harder to answer your questions in a way you understand. Because I'm assuming you care about the implementation and since you already asked about the drawbacks, I'll remove all the questions about drawbacks from your question. Note that "I need the DSP implementation of"… sounds like a request for code written to your specification, and that's off-topic. It also demonstrates no research of your own – there's much software that you can find that implements a (approximate) Hilbert transform.

Now, you don't actually need that implementation to "know the reasons of delay and complexity"; that's honestly just really basic theory of digital systems. You could ask that question without asking for an implementation, and you should take care to phrase it sensibly. You learned in Dan's answer that "we can cover any band of frequencies we need and come as close to DC as needed at the expense of filter complexity and delay", and it seems to me you're slightly conflating "come as close to DC" with "wide band of frequencies":

If your signal's bandwidth is wide, and you don't care to what happens to a wide range of frequencies below and above that wide band, then the complexity is not necessarily high. It's the "defining arbitrary bands" and "getting as close to DC" is what gets you. One should probably also add that your requirements in flatness in the bands you work on is important.

The normal way we implement a delayed Hilbert Transformer is with an FIR filter having odd-symmetry about its FIR midpoint.  The way we do that is to first design the non-causal Hilbert transformer with zero phase (other than the $-\frac\pi2$) and then delay it later to make it causal. Usually the way we do it is to take the ideal theoretical impulse response
$$\begin{align} h[n] &= \begin{cases}
 \frac{1 - (-1)^n}{\pi n} \quad & n \ne 0 \\
\\
0 & n = 0
\end{cases}
\\
\\
&= \begin{cases}
 \frac{2}{\pi n} \quad\quad\quad & n \text{ odd} \\
\\
0 &  n \text{ even}
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$
and window it with a good window (I recommend Kaiser unless you find yourself a better window).  The longer the window, the wider bandwidth of the Hilbert transformer.
Remember that you have to delay the symmetrical Hilbert transform FIR to make it causal and then you must also delay the in-phase component by the same amount so that the in-phase and quadrature components maintain that phase relationship of $-\frac\pi2$.
What is the algorithm to do a Discrete Hilbert Transform?

And the longer the window the less amplitude ripple (error) in this window based "full-band" solution (as well as get closer with that accuracy to DC and Nyquist which is the bandwidth Robert refers to).

Yup, but with that $\beta$ parameter in the Kaiser window, that can be traded off with the transition band, which for the Hilbert transformer, is at DC.  This was an issue for audio and the bottom couple of octaves.  I remember doing a Hilbert that was something like 500 samples long.  I think I had 250 MAC instructions.  I had to do that to get good amplitude out at even 50 Hz with the sample rate at 44.1 kHz or 48 kHz.

Right, makes sense. 50Hz means 100 Hz transition band, and at 48 KHz and 80 dB aliasing (if for example you wanted that) fred harris' rule of thumb comes out to 80/22 * 48e3/100 = 1745 taps if doing it with an FIR!
